# Why does this one-line JS not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, onmouseover

http://jsfiddle.net/Gch83/

```
<input id="myRadioButton1" name="radiobutton" value="radiobutton" type="radio">1
<input id="myRadioButton2" name="radiobutton" value="radiobutton" type="radio">2

<input value="1 checked" onMouseOver="document.all.myRadioButton1.checked = true;" type="button">
<input value="2 checked" onMouseOver="document.all.myRadioButton2.checked = true;" type="button">
```

Hovering over the buttons changes the radio buttons in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<input value="1 checked" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('myRadioButton1').checked = true;" type="button">

<input value="2 checked" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('myRadioButton2').checked = true;" type="button">
```

The [reason](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/) is that `document.all` is not supported by FF as it was introduced by IE and is not standard DOM.

A demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gch83/3).

Answer (score 3):

[Don't Use `document.all`](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/) instead use `document.getElementById()` that should do the trick !

Answer (score 2):

use `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `document.all`

Answer (score 2):

just do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/duante/Gch83/2/

Answer (score 1):

Basically said, the use of **document.all** is non-standard.

In fact, it's something that javascript programmers ought to avoid. It's a relic of Internet Explorer 4 (circa 1997!), and was included because there were some very fundamental DOM APIs which were yet to be standardized at that time (such as **document.getElementById**). If a modern browser supports any of these old DOM APIs, it is simply for the sake of compatibility with very old programs. WebKit will still return an HTMLCollection type for **document.all**, which is why you noticed that your code works in the Chrome browser. But modern versions of Firefox have deliberately decided to drop support for it, and instead will return the **undefined** value.

The recommended approach here would be to use **document.getElementById** to get references to the elements you'd like to control (you can add ids to the second pair of elements), and then register event handlers on those elements from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`document.all` only works in Firefox when the page is in quirks mode (which is something you definitely don't want to be in).

[Don't use `document.all`](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/).

It was created before W3C had standardised `getElementById()`.

> `document.all` is a proprietary feature of Microsoft Internet Explorer

[Source](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/08/firefox-documentall-caveat.html).

Use modern, W3C compliant methods instead.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('my-checkbox');
document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   checkbox.checked = true;
}, false);
```

...and you'll need to do some research about IE's `attachEvent()`.